# opening a .exe (c program) from c#

Tags: c#, c++

I want to open an executable c/c++ program from c# that includes giving inputs. I have used Process.Start() but it supports only command line arguments is there any way to pass the arguments to a cin or scanf function??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `Process.RedirectStandardInput` and then you can write information to the `Process.StandardInput` stream.

See the example at MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx